# unserialize.com how they do it

Tags: php, json

I got the following string:

```
a:16:{i:0;s:1:"6";i:1;s:2:"12";i:2;s:1:"2";i:3;s:2:"11";i:4;s:1:"7";i:5;s:2:"10";i:6;s:2:"16";i:7;s:1:"5";i:8;s:1:"3";i:9;s:1:"1";i:10;s:2:"14";i:11;s:1:"8";i:12;s:2:"13";i:13;s:1:"9";i:14;s:1:"4";i:15;s:2:"15";}
```

I can't use

```
var_dump(json_decode($json))
```

because it doesn't return anything. I found 2 websites that where a bit usefull:
http://jsonlint.com/ for checking if the object is valid (what it ain't) and http://www.unserialize.com/ wich can 'unserialize' the json string back to an array.

Now I wonder what unserialize does to the json string. So I can use it in my script as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this is in serialized form. You need to use [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function here.

```
$input = 'a:16:{i:0;s:1:"6";i:1;s:2:"12";i:2;s:1:"2";i:3;s:2:"11";i:4;s:1:"7";i:5;s:2:"10";i:6;s:2:"16";i:7;s:1:"5";i:8;s:1:"3";i:9;s:1:"1";i:10;s:2:"14";i:11;s:1:"8";i:12;s:2:"13";i:13;s:1:"9";i:14;s:1:"4";i:15;s:2:"15";}';

var_dump(unserialize($input));
```

Comment: Now I really feel stupid. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Use unserialize function in php

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r(unserialize('a:16:{i:0;s:1:"6";i:1;s:2:"12";i:2;s:1:"2";i:3;s:2:"11";i:4;s:1:"7";i:5;s:2:"10";i:6;s:2:"16";i:7;s:1:"5";i:8;s:1:"3";i:9;s:1:"1";i:10;s:2:"14";i:11;s:1:"8";i:12;s:2:"13";i:13;s:1:"9";i:14;s:1:"4";i:15;s:2:"15";}'));
?>
```

https://eval.in/637790